# Publish Android Lint results from Pipeline project

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-workflow, android-lint, jenkins-pipeline

I am building an Android project with Jenkins (2.0 Beta) as a Pipeline.

From a Freestyle job I can archive the build results using a post build action Publish Android Lint Results.

My Pipeline script is:

```
node {
    stage 'Checkout'
    git branch: 'final', url: 'https://github.com/LordRaydenMK/android-testing/'

    stage 'Build'
    sh './gradlew clean assemble'

    stage 'Android Lint'
    sh './gradlew lint'

    stage 'Lint Results'
    //How to archive the results ?

    stage 'Test'
    sh './gradlew test'

    stage 'JUnit tests'
    step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: 'app/build/test-results/*/TEST-*.xml'])
}
```

I am running lint and the results are saved in a file. I don't know how to  publish the results so the Android Lint Plugin can pick them up.

JUnit results are archived fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking trough the source code I realized the published version (2.2) is not compatible with Pipeline.

Version 2.3 with pipeline compatibility is not released yet.

Update: Version 2.3 of the Android Lint Plugin was released. To archive the results you can use

```
step([$class: 'LintPublisher', pattern: 'app/build/outputs/lint-results*.xml'])
```